# Regex TRYING to search with multiple criteria or backwards

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, re2

Appreciating regex but still beginning.

I tried many workarounds but can't figure how to solve my problem.

String A : 4 x 120glgt

String B : 120glgt

I'd like the proper regex to return 120 as the number after `"x"`.
But sometimes there won't be `"x"`. So, be it [A] or [B] looking for one unique approach.

I tried :

1. to start the search from the END
2. Start right after the "x"

I clearly have some syntax issues and didn't quite get the logic of `(?=)`

`(?=[^x])(?=[0-9]+)`

So looking forward to learn with your help

Comment: if glgt is always there you can look for digits before it, with ` \d+(?=glgt)`

Comment: Thanks Tomas. glglt was just an example.

Answer (score 1):

As you tagged pcre, you could optionally match the leading digits followed by x and use `\K` to clear the match buffer to only match the digits after it.

```
^(?:\d+\h*x\h*)?\K\d+
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `(?:\d+\h*x\h*)?` Optionally match 1+ digits followed by `x` between optional spaces
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `\d+` Match 1+ digits

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6SNSkY/1).

If you want to use a lookahead variant, you might use

```
\d+(?=[^\r\n\dx]*$)
```

This pattern matches:

- `\d+` Match 1+ digits
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is to the right is

  - `[^\r\n\dx]*$` Match optional repetitions of any char except a digit, `x` or a newline
- `)` Close the lookahead

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/X2CmIr/1).

Comment: @fourth thx a lot. GSheets REGEXEXTRACT invokes regex syntax error. If someone knows how to transcribe to GSheets regex syntax...

Comment: @DavidABITEBOUL Try it with REGEXREPLACE, match `^(?:\d+\h*x\h*)?(\d+).+` and replace with capture group 1 like `"$1"` See https://regex101.com/r/6ApGxb/1

Comment: @fourth I still can't get it. Sorry for my dumbiness. I share a little GSheet with the [example](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12v5BgH9KwLeCPNEymbelvHmc4uMNDeGnnBgy2f2umww/edit?usp=sharing) with, of course, edition rights.

Comment: @DavidABITEBOUL It could be like this `=REGEXREPLACE(A2,"^(?:\d+\s*x\s*)?(\d+).+", "$1")`  See https://imgur.com/a/OJDijQ0 Or use `=REGEXEXTRACT(A2,"^(?:\d+\s*x\s*)?(\d+)")`